# How to keep a page fixed

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, browser, web-inspector

Hello i want to **Inspect Element** in Browser (FireFox 87) but the Page **update** the Content every 1 second so the inspect jumps to main `Div` of the page,The site address is as follows :

[Page Address](http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=2400322364771558)

So Is there a way I can keep the page **steady** other than disconnecting from the internet *(that Work)* ?

Answer (score 0):

use position: fixed in your menu button instead of absolute

```
#menu_btns {
display: block;
position: fixed;
z-index: 800;
top: 8px;
left: 20px;
height: 32px;
width: 580px;
}
```

by doing this your problem will be , this is just for fix menu if you want to fix entire page add position fixed in MainContainer

.MainContainer {

```
text-align: center;

position: fixed;
```

}

add position:fixed in css rule whatever you want to fix

Comment: Actually, I need a better method, but thank you for taking the time and guide me ;)